# ruby's any equivalent in liquid?

Tags: liquid

I want to show sepcific text `if` the product.variants title == "size" or "Size"

I tried this:
UPDATE - this would be the right way but still not happening with same results

```
{% for option in product.options %}
    {%- if option == "size" or "Size" -%}
         <p id="green-hover">Review size before adding to cart.</p>
    {% break %}
    {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}

{% for option in product.options %}
    {%- if option contains "size" or "Size" -%}
         <p id="green-hover">Review size before adding to cart.</p>
    {% break %}
    {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

In ruby, I would do:

```
@product.options.any? { |option| option== "size" || "Size" }
```

Something like that at least, not tested - don't flame me.

What can I do that allows me to check if the product.variants title equals a certain string or value?

Comment: actually in Ruby it would just be `option[/size/i]`

Comment: Is that the regex way you're saying? Wouldn't the `any?` work?

Comment: indeed, when you see the /.../ pattern it is a regular expression
`option[/size/i]` returns the sting "size" if present in option, smalls or capitals, and `nil` if not present
`any?` doesn't work on `String` nor `nil`, or doe you mean something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
{% assign option_titles = product.options | join: ' ' %}
   {% if option_titles contains 'Size' %}
   <p id="green-hover">Review size before adding to cart.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that `#any?` here would be super useful, but Liquid doesn't have that capability. It's a bit kludgy since you want to look for both "size" and "Size", but this should work:

```
{%- for option in product.options %}
  {%- if option contains "size" or option contains "Size" %}
    <p id="green-hover">Review size before adding to cart.</p>
  {% break %}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

If you have an `and` or `or` in a condition, you need to repeat the whole condition twice. So `if option contains "size" or option contains "Size"` instead of `if option contains "size" or "Size"`.